# Handle multiple datasource in single transaction with using AbstractRoutingDataSource SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

How can I handle multiple datasource in single transaction?

Background:

1. Dynamic datasource (e.g. sometimes there are 3 databases, sometimes there are 4 databases) that's why I have to use AbstractRoutingDataSource to switch database in programme.

What I expect to see is: when database2.save() fail, all the things in this transaction has to be rolled backed.

```
@transaction
public void saving(){
   database1.save();
   database2.save();
}
```

I have done many research of using JTATransaction manager or XA datasource. i don't know if it really works in this case. And there is lack of sample code. Moreover, I noticed that ChainedTransactionManager was already deprecated.